# acetic acid 50% safety and storage

Tags: safety

I need <5% acetic acid in some solutions (for microscopy) and if I am not wrong I need around 15-20% solution to be able to make these (other components like alcohols or glycerol I can find and use near 100%). I can find 50% acetic acid easily to purchase, and I am planning to dilute this to 20% or 25% immediately for storage and use later (all at home). Other than having straightforward PPE (goggles, gloves, lab coat, respirator if needed) and following the basic acid dilution procedure (adding acid to water etc.), is there any safety issue I should be aware of? I.e. I do not have a fume extractor.

I see different information in a few places but usually I read organic acids are compatible with alcohols for storage, so I assume I can store it together with for example IPA 99% ? I have a safety cabinet for flammable liquids which I use to keep alcohol based things.

Comment: As you are diluting a solution which is not concentrated, you can simply add your acidic solution in enough water, and stir. Nothing will happen. There are no safety issue that you should be aware of.

Comment: OK, so can I derive a take home message that there is a major difference, in terms of handling, between 50% and glacial forms ?

Comment: No ! Dilutimg glacial acid is weakly exothermic when mixing it with water. But you should remember that acid must always be dropped into water, and not the contrary.

Comment: OK. The reason I said this is reading/watching things about glacial acetic acid worried me a bit, so I want to know if/to what extent 50% is safer. I also see glacial has a bit different categorizations (transport numbers etc.) than solutions. Now from your answer I understand although glacial acid is more concentrated, it is (being weak) not very dangerous and 50% is not very different than that in terms of handling (naturally still with enough PPE, but proper/full lab environment not needed). Is that right ?

Comment: Acetic acid is called glacial when it is 100% pure. This name comes from the fact that, if a bottle of this acid is dipped into a bath made of melting ice, it freezes. This does not happen with significantly diluted solutions of acetic acid.